# Linear dependent subset? Need help understanding a nuance of a definition

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$, and let $S \subset V$.
$S$ is **linearly dependent** if there exist a finite number of distinct vectors $x_1,x_2,...,x_n \in S$ and scalars $a_1,a_2,...,a_n \in F$(not all zero) such that

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_ix_i = 0$

I don't fully comprehend it.

Say, $0 \in S$. Then $\forall a \in F \ \ 0 = a0$.The vector is zero, but the scalar $a$ needn't be. **Or does it means "not all zero" for both vectors and scalars?**

Now, whatever the answer to the first issue is, say $x_1,...,x_n$ are linearly dependent, that is, $\exists a_1,...,a_n$ such that

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_ix_i = 0$

Does this mean that $\{x_1,...,x_n\} \cup A$ is linearly dependent $\forall \ \ A \subset V$?

That being said, does this mean that a union of linearly dependent subset with ANY other subset of $V$ is linearly dependent, that is, we don't care about the properties of an other subset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your first question, your definition of linear dependence is correct, and what you have done is proved that any set containing the zero vector is indeed a linearly dependent set. To your second question, yes. (And it looks like you already know how to prove it! :) )

Comment: So(sorry if I'm asking basically the same), a linearly dependent subset of $V$ is any subset of $V$ containing any subset of linearly dependent vectors? This somehow feels strange to me, that is, what's the point of having such definition? It tells us little.

Comment: Yes, the definition just says that there is *some* linear relation between a finite number of the elements of $S.$ Indeed, that doesn't change of you add more elements to $S$. But that doesn't mean that the definition isn't useful!

Answer (score 1):

Not all zero is only for scalars.

Look at it in the following way: Let us first understand what it means to say that two distinct vectors $x_1$ and $x_2$ are linearly dependent. It simply means that one of them is a scalar multiple of the other, i.e., $x_1=\lambda x_2$. In this case we don't have any restriction on $\lambda$. $\lambda can be zero as well.$ Let us now see what this yields: It says that there exist scalars &\lambda, -1& such that $\lambda x_1-x_2=0$. Notice that not both scalars are zero($-1 \neq 0$). Here, we began with a given set of two distinct vectors.

If we have a given set of $n$ distinct vectors, say $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$, then they are said to be dependent if at least one of them can be written as some linear combination of the others. This  implies that there exists scalars $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_{n-1}$ such that at least one of the vectors (say $x_n$ wlog) is given by $x_n = \lambda_1 x_1+...+\lambda_{n-1}x_{n-1}$. Again in this definition we don't need $\lambda_k,1\leq k \leq n-1$ to be not all zero! All of them can be zero and yet the vectors $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ will be linearly dependent. But then how do you translate this definition into the standard one? Well in this case you have $ \lambda_1 x_1+...+\lambda_{n-1}x_{n-1}-x_n=0$ where $-1\neq 0.$ Can you see now that why they say that "a set of $n$ distinct vectors are linearly dependent if there exist a set of $n$ scalars not all zero such that $ \lambda_1 x_1+...+\lambda_{n-1}x_{n-1}+\lambda_nx_n=0$?"

Now suppose there is a set $S\subseteq V$. How to define the notion of a dependent set? $S$ can be infinite! Here is a simple way. A set $S$ will be called dependent if you are able to find a finite subset of $S$ (consisting of distinct vectors) which are linearly dependent in the above sense. This answers your last question as well. Because if you already have a linearly dependent set then its union with any other set will still have those finite set of linearly dependent distinct vectors and hence will be dependent.

Comment: I have another "pathological" example in mind. Say, $S = \{x_0=0,x_1,...,x_n \}$ is some arbitrary set of vectors(of a linear space $V$ over $F$) **containing 0**. So, $0, x_1, ... , x_n$  are **always** linearly dependent, because $\forall x_i \in V, 1 \leq i \leq n \ \ \forall a_0 \in F, a_0 \neq 0: a_00 + 0x_1 + ... + 0x_n = 0$. Not all scalars are zero, since $a_0$ is not. But $x_0$ is the zero vector. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. The set is indeed dependent. In fact you proved that any set of vectors containing $0$ is necessarily dependent.